# OR logic in Angular for returning in $watch()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is this OR syntax/logic wrong in Angular.js if the object doesn't exist? I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'timestamp' of undefined`. But I verified in the chrome debugger at least one of these exist such as `sseHandler.result.httpPortResult.timestamp`.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
             return sseHandler.result.cpuResult.timestamp ||
                 sseHandler.result.networkResult.timestamp ||
                 sseHandler.result.httpPortResult.timestamp;
}, function(){
    if (sseHandler.result.cpuResult) {
        console.log("yes");
             cpuUpdate(sseHandler.result);
    }
   });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to just do `$scope.$watchCollection(sseHandler.result, function() { });`, but I'm not sure if that will meet your needs as it will fire for any change to sseHandler.result, not just the timestamps.

Otherwise you need to check if the properties exist, and I doubt the way you have it now will even catch a change on networkResult, as if cpuResult hasn't changed it will return that, and angular will think nothing has changed.  So I would probably do it like:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
         var ret = '';
         if (sseHandler.result.cpuResult) 
             ret += sseHandler.result.cpuResult.timestamp;
         if (sseHandler.result.networkResult)
             ret += sseHandler.result.networkResult.timestamp;
         if (sseHandler.result.httpPortResult)
             ret += sseHandler.result.httpPortResult.timestamp;
         return ret; 
      }, function() {});
```

Comment: +1 to $watchCollection. I wish Angular.js  documentation had a finer index for their api collection.